# Reordenar AUTO_INCREMENT de forma correta

Tags: mysql, auto-incremento

Oi,

Preciso reordenar o campo **AUTO_INCREMENT** no **MySql** para que fique na sequencia correta. Pesquisando, eu consegui faze-lo mas quando insiro um novo registro, ele fica com o *Id* continuado da ordem anterior. Exemplos:

ANTES

Id's: 1, 2, 4, 5, 7...

REORDENADO

Id's: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...

APÓS NOVO REGISTRO

Id's: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8.

Como faço para reordenar e continuar corretamente?

Comment: por que não cria uma coluna `codigo` pra controlar isso?

Comment: Como seria a correção no caso de desordem?

Comment: se você não tem um campo que consegue ordenar, tipo data de cadastro ou código, acredito que terá que fazer manual mesmo..

Answer (score -1):

Fala amigo, tente editar o código do registro de 8 para 6 e depois rode este comando:

ALTER TABLE  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1